# xrandr - LDVS1 detected but doesn't actually exist

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr

I have a PC-Mini with one DVI output -- and nothing else. When I check xrandr I see this:

```
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768       60.0 +
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1400x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
   640x400        70.0
```

Anyway I have it disabled, just confused as to why it would even appear and if anyone can help me shed some light on it. Double kudos if anyone can tell me why my DVI appears to be an HDMI in xrandr. Thanks